# Empty Cells in CollectionView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am facing a very weird issue, I am showing categories to user using horizontal `CollectionView` in `Xamarin.iOS` and i am using `MvvMCross` as well. The issue is that that when i scroll the categories `CollectionView` and scroll back some of the cells are empty.

This is the code for the subclass of the `MvxCollectionViewCell` in which i am binding values to the UI.

```
public partial class DealListCategoryCollectionCellView : MvxCollectionViewCell
    {
        public static readonly UINib Nib = UINib.FromName("DealListCategoryCollectionCellView", NSBundle.MainBundle);
        public static readonly NSString Key = new NSString("CategoryCollectionViewCell");
        private FXMvxImageViewLoader _imageLoader;

        public DealListCategoryCollectionCellView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            _imageLoader = new FXMvxImageViewLoader(() => CategoryImageView);
            this.DelayBind(() =>
            {

                var set = this.CreateBindingSet<DealListCategoryCollectionCellView, CategoryCellViewModel>();
                set.Bind(TitleLabel).To(vm => vm.Name);
                set.Bind(_imageLoader).To(vm => vm.Slug).WithConversion("LocalImage", "icons");
                set.Apply();

            });
        }

        public static DealListCategoryCollectionCellView Create()
        {
            return (DealListCategoryCollectionCellView)Nib.Instantiate(null, null)[0];
        }
    }
```

And this is how i am binding the above collectionview Cell.

```
 CategoryCollectionView.RegisterNibForCell(DealListCategoryCollectionCellView.Nib, DealListCategoryCollectionCellView.Key);
var categorySource = new MvxCollectionViewSource(CategoryCollectionView,DealListCategoryCollectionCellView.Key);

CategoryCollectionView.Source = categorySource;
```

And this is the screenshot of the issue :[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by first changing this:

```
CategoryCollectionView.Source = categorySource;
```

to:

```
CategoryCollectionView.DataSource = categorySource;
```

So when i changed from `Source` to `DataSource` the empty cell issue was fixed but there was another issue my tap on cell was not being fired. So i implemented `CollectionViewDelegate` like this:

```
class CategoryCollectionDelegate : UICollectionViewDelegate
    {
        DealListViewModel viewModel;
        public CategoryCollectionDelegate(DealListViewModel vm)
        {
            viewModel = vm;
        }
        public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            Category currentCategory = viewModel.Categories[indexPath.Row];
            Console.WriteLine(currentCategory.Name);
            viewModel.DoSelectCategoryCommand(currentCategory);
        }
    }
```

And than i used it like that :

```
CategoryCollectionView.Delegate = new CategoryCollectionDelegate(DealListViewModel);
```

And it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

the solution for me was to overwrite the CellDisplayingEnded method in the CollectionViewSource. As you see here https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Binding/iOS/Views/MvxBaseCollectionViewSource.cs there is some commented code in CellDisplayingEnded method which maybe in some version of mvvmcross is not commented and dataContext is set to null.